# How to modify jqGrid with object literal

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way to modify a row like...

```
var params = {
    name: "John",
    age: 13,
    email: "asd@asd.com",
    ...
    //You get the point
}
grid.jqGrid('editColumnMethodFromJqGrid', 3, params);
```

...supposing that name, age and email are columns of the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that out.
With new version of the API:

```
var params = {
    //Defined in answer
}
$("#grid").jqGrid('setRowData', "row_id", data);
```